# What mushrooms can I grow on kitchen waste?

Tags: mushrooms

I've got a box where kitchen waste, old pasta, lettuce etc, goes for composting. If I could grow mushrooms on it I'd try that so are there any that would ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that kitchen waste would need to be sterilized before you would have any luck beating out mold. better to compost it, and then inoculate your compost pile with some appropriate mushrooms from [field and forest](http://www.fieldforest.net/) or [fungi perfecti](http://www.fungi.com/).